# WP7 - Adding Tiles to App ( Pin to start) error

Tags: windows-phone-7, addition, tile

I was just wondering if there was a legitimate way to create and add tiles from my app. Since im making this app which takes notes and saves it i was wondering if there was a way to do this. I have windows Phone 7.8 installed and have the latest SDK. Im looking for this feature, with all three tile sizes supported and update as well.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
 Public Shared Sub CreateTile(uri As Uri, tiledata As ShellTileData, usewide As Boolean)
    Dim shellTileType As Type = Type.[GetType]("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone")
    Dim Createmethod As MethodInfo = shellTileType.GetMethod("Create", {GetType(Uri), GetType(ShellTileData), GetType(Boolean)})
    Createmethod.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {uri, tiledata, usewide})
End Sub
Private Shared Sub SetProperty(instance As Object, name As String, value As Object)
    Dim setMethod = instance.[GetType]().GetProperty(name).GetSetMethod()
    setMethod.Invoke(instance, New Object() {value})
End Sub
Private Sub PinToStart_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim Storage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim data As SampleData = TryCast(TryCast(sender, MenuItem).DataContext, SampleData)
    Dim selectedItem As ListBoxItem = TryCast(Me.SavedNotesList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data), ListBoxItem)
    Dim FS As IsolatedStorageFileStream = Storage.OpenFile("MyNote/SavedNotes/" & data.FileNameX, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim FETime As String = Storage.GetCreationTime("MyNote/SavedNotes/" & data.FileNameX).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy h:mmtt")
    Using SR As New StreamReader(FS)
        Dim newTile As ShellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("/CreateNote.xaml?tile=" & data.FileNameX))
        If newTile Is Nothing Then
            Dim tileDataType As Type = Type.[GetType]("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IconicTileData, Microsoft.Phone")
            Dim IconicTileData As ShellTileData = DirectCast(tileDataType.GetConstructor(New Type() {}).Invoke(Nothing), ShellTileData)
            SetProperty(IconicTileData, "Title", data.FileNameX)
            SetProperty(IconicTileData, "BackgroundColor", Colors.Transparent)
            SetProperty(IconicTileData, "IconImage", New Uri("\Assets\202.png", UriKind.Relative))
            SetProperty(IconicTileData, "SmallIconImage", New Uri("\Assets\110.png", UriKind.Relative))
            SetProperty(IconicTileData, "WideContent1", SR.ReadLine)
            SetProperty(IconicTileData, "WideContent2", SR.ReadLine)
            SetProperty(IconicTileData, "WideContent3", FETime)
            CreateTile(New Uri("/CreateNote.xaml?Titletxt=" & data.FileNameX & "&Bodytxt=" & data.Description, UriKind.Relative), IconicTileData, True)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("The tile has been pin to start!")
        End If
    End Using       
End Sub
```

Soo far i managed to create it and it works! But there is one problem. Once the user clicks the tile, it goes to the CreateNote page where the user views it. but the user has no control of the file as in the file can't be edited or saved or anything. Its basically just a view only thing. How can i make it so that when the user clicks the tile, it goes to the "CreateNote" page with all the functionalitys enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the resources for Windows Phone, they're really great.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574(v=vs.105).aspx